# Access self of outer context

Tags: ruby, oop, email

I have some code that looks like this:

```
  class Wrapper
    def get_email_body rdv
      body = "<h1>There is an appointment available!</h1><br>"
      body += "Title: <b>#{rdv['title']}</b><br>"
      body += "Date: <b>#{rdv['start']}</b><br>"
      body + "Link: <a href='#{rdv['link']}'>"
    end

    def send_email rdv
      TARGET_EMAIL_ADDRESSES.each do|email|
        Mail.deliver do
          to email
          from 'my_email_address'
          subject 'Appointments available!'
          html_part do
            content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
            body get_email_body(rdv)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When `send_email` is called with an object that represents an appointment, I get the exception:

```
  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail/message.rb:1396:in `method_missing': undefined method `get_email_body' for #<Mail::Part:0x000055ba3e9f60c0> (NoMethodError)
```

I noticed that inside the block given to Mail.deliver, `self` is a `#<Mail::Part:560, Multipart: false, Headers: <Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8>>` object.

I understand that the block is ran by an instance method of the Mail class, and that's the reason why `self` is different.

Is it possible to access the Wrapper object, `self` of the outer context, and call the `get_email_body` instance method ? preferably without making it a class method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the email body before calling `Mail.deliver`.

```rb
def send_email(rdv)
  email_body = get_email_body(rdv) # evaluate

  TARGET_EMAIL_ADDRESSES.each do |email|
    Mail.deliver do
      to email
      from 'my_email_address'
      subject 'Appointments available!'
      html_part do
        content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        body email_body # pass the value
      end
    end
  end
end
```